# Posting a string from client to mongoDB in express node .js using Sails

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js

Attempting to post a string from client to mongoDB in Sails

val is a string posted in real time from the client to the server database

**POST Form**( is html the right choice here? )

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="post" method="post">
        <p>
            <label for="val">'Enter val'</label>
            <input type="text" name="val" autofocus />
            <input type="submit" />
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

`

**routes.js** (?)

```
'/post': {controller: "PostController", action: "post"}
```

**Post.js**

```
module.exports = {
```

attributes: {
    val: {
        type: 'string',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
  }
}

**PostController.js** (?)

```
module.exports = {
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
  app.post : function (req, res) {
  var val = req.body.val;   
  return res.send ('val': val);
  todo: 'Now how do I start loading into mongoDB ?';
}}
```

**app.js**

```
?
```

KEY QUESTION

How does val goes from the client to the database, that is :

what is the right sequence of events between component files in Sails ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to go through and read documentation learn how sails works.

Try
https://Sailsjs.org

and / or

http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2015/01/01/lets-start-a-new-adventure/

For starters your controller is not written correctly

```
module.exports = {
  post : function (req, res) {
         var val = req.param('val');   
         return res.send ({'val': val});
     }
}
```

This should help a little, but your code was written in a way that says that your very unfamiliar with how sails works in general. You should read the docs or watch those videos linked above to get you started.

Comment: we all were at once :). Those videos are new this year, they are a good resource!

Comment: Thank you for fixing the controller

Comment: **req.param ('val')** VS **req.body ('val')** ?

Comment: if using req.body then it would be req.body.val , req.param('val') is a catch all for query, body and parameters. So either way. req.param('val') allows you to also test with a query string, but if you know its a body param then just use body as it would be (mildly) more performant